# Fastest reading through i2c

Tags: i2c, accelerometer

I have an ADXL345 accelerometer and I read it with an arduino through I2C. I want to get readings at a frequency higher than 500Hz. According to the documentation this should be easily achievable, however I've downloaded and used multiple libraries and none of them was able to achieve a sampling rate higher than 100Hz. They were all based on the arduino Wire library which doesn't seen very efficient. Could someone point me to a library or give me pieces of code that will allow me to sample data at 500+Hz? I send the data to matlab, not that it probably matters.

Answer (score 1):

If you want highest possible frequency, I'd use SPI instead.
With 16 MHz Arduino, SPI clock can be 4MHz.

The chip only supports I2C at 400 KHz clock, which is way slower.
http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL345.pdf

Comment: If you set the SPI2X: Double SPI Speed Bit, you can run at 8MHz, but the ADXL345 only support upto 5Mhz.

Comment: Yes, 16MHz Arduino can run SPI clock at 1 MHz, 2 MHz, 4 MHz (default speed), 8 MHz (and 4 additional slower speeds - but not 5 MHz). I use 8 MHz for a lot of shift register projects.

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't SPI require to convert between 5 to 3.3V for the arduino? In any case,  400KHz would be far more than I need but I fail to reach that sampling rate with the Wire library.

Comment: 5V down to 3.3V, and 3.3V up to 5V is easily down with a couple of chips. 74HC4050, sN74HC125